# How do I get rid of the white gap above the keyboard in iPhone X Safari?

Tags: ios, keyboard, mobile-safari, iphone-x

I'm developing a site that has to work on iOS Safari. When the keyboard isn't showing, it looks like this:

[image]

When I focus on the "Send a message..." input, thereby bringing up the keyboard, it looks like this:

[image]

Note the white gap between the keyboard and the red input area.

How do I get rid of this gap? Please note that making a native iOS app is not an option.

Comment: The view above the keyboard is direct inserted on the view or you are using as an `inputAccessoryView`?

Comment: @kileros: Views are not applicable here, as far as I know. This is a React website in the Safari mobile browser.

Comment: my bad, I did not see that you are working with an website. You can check for something about keyboard tool bar or input accessory view, I believe that the problem is associated with one of them.